# next js make dynamic human readble urls

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am using next js and i want to make human readble urls like the urls of stackoverflow questions for each of my webpages using "-" betwwen each words but i dont know how to do it
corrently my url looks like this

**localhost:3001/Morbius%OTT%release%date%confirmed%3F**

i want to convert this in to this

**localhost:3001/Morbius-OTT-release-date-confirmed-?**

```
<div className="question11">
            {data.map((itm) => (
              <Link
                key={itm._id}
                href={{
                  pathname: "query/[itm]",
                }}
                as={`/${encodeURIComponent(itm.Name)}`}
              >
                <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the spaces with dashes before encoding the `itm.name`:

```js
encodeURIComponent("Morbius OTT release date confirmed ?".replace(/ /g, "-"))
// Output: Morbius-OTT-release-date-confirmed-%3F
```

Code:

```js
<div className="question11">
            {data.map((itm) => (
              <Link
                key={itm._id}
                href={{
                  pathname: "query/[itm]",
                }}
                as={`query/${encodeURIComponent(itm.name.replace(/ /g, "-"))}`}
              >
                <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
```

Remove special characters (except `.`, `-`, `_`, `.`, and `~` since they don't need to be encoded) if you don't want them encoded:

```
              <Link
                key={itm._id}
                href={{
                  pathname: "query/[itm]",
                }}
                as={`/query/${encodeURIComponent(itm.name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 - _ . ~]/g, "").replace(/ /g, "-"))}`}
              >
```

Comment: oke this answer is working to some extend but secial charactors such as ? are not in human readble form i want that also to be in human readbale form then only i can accept ur answer

Comment: @jisaks I added code to remove special characters since they are encoded by default, most special characters are either encoded or removed from url, even in stackoverflow if you go to a question that has a "?" in the title the url will exclude it

Comment: ? is reserved for url encoding.URL encoder just replace the question marks with %3F.